# How to reconcile 'this' referencing DOM element and 'this' referencing class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, this

I'm having an issue understanding how I might go about using the `this` keyword to refer to a DOM element that is has been clicked, but also using that inside a class where `this` usually refers to the instance of that class.

Here's a snippet of the relevant code:

```js
class Passwords {
  constructor() {
    $('.password-column button.steel-button').on('click', this.selectButton);
  }
  
  selectButton() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
    this.columnController();
  }
  
  columnController(){
    // A function that does something else
  }
}
```

The issue I'm having is that it doesn't recognize `columnController()` as a function.
I imagine this is because of the scope and how it works with 'this', but I'm not sure how to proceed.

In the above code, `selectButton()` is successfully applied to all the buttons specified, but the error is given on `this.columnController()`.
Exact console error is:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.columnController is not a function

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `this` to represent both objects, so pick one and get the other one through some other mechanism.

For example: Use an arrow function to bind the `this` value to the class, then get the element from the `event` object.

```js
class Passwords {
  constructor() {
    $('.password-column button.steel-button').on('click', this.selectButton);
  }

  selectButton = (event) => {
    $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('selected');
    this.columnController();
  }

  columnController() {
    console.log("this runs");
  }
}

new Passwords();
```

```css
.selected {
  background: blue
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="password-column">
  <button class="steel-button">click</button>
</div>
```

Comment: …or alternatively, store the class instance in a closure variable (`const that = this`), and access the element using `this`.

Comment: Selected as correct answer, although notably it marks event.currentTarget as depreciated. Does work though.

Comment: The [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/event.currenttarget/) says that currentTarget was added in v1.3 but does not say it is deprecated.